# Integral Cuboid Problem

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Any progress in solving the [`integral cuboid problem`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectCuboid.html)?: Find a "brick" of integral dimensions a, b, c such that the 3 face-centered diagonals based on (a,b), (b,c), (a,c) AND the "body" diagonal based on (a,b,c) are all integral? Progress: theoretical or experimental.

Comment: Wrong stack? I'd venture you're after math or mathoverflow...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: I don't really see that I'm in the WRONG stack. WolframMathworld has an entry called "Perfect Cuboid". So I'm asking: Are there are any new Mathematica approaches to this kind of Diophantine equations? Nevertheless, I will also post this elsewhere as proposed...

Answer (score 3):

Currently, using [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html), or [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html), Mathematica can neither solve the problem nor prove that a solution does not exist.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[d[s_List]] := Subscript[d, StringJoin[ToString /@ s]]

sides = {a, b, c};

eqns = Assuming[Thread[sides > 0],
   d[#] == (Norm[#] // Simplify) & /@
    Subsets[sides, {2, 3}]];

Solve[eqns, sides, Integers]
```

[image]

```
Reduce[eqns, sides, Integers]
```

[image]

```
FindInstance[eqns, sides, Integers]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Equivalent results are obtained after adding inequalities to the equations.

```
eqns2 = Module[{ss = Subsets[sides, {2, 3}]},
  Join[
   Assuming[Thread[sides > 0],
      d[#] == (Norm[#] // Simplify)] & /@ ss,
   Thread[sides > 0], Thread[(d /@ ss) > 0]]]
```

[image]

```
Solve[eqns2, sides, Integers, MaxExtraConditions -> All]

Reduce[eqns2, sides, Integers]

FindInstance[eqns2, sides, Integers]
```

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk - The results of your code contain conditions like `Element[Subscript[d, "ab"] | 
          Subscript[d, "abc"] | 
          ... | Sqrt[
            -3*Subscript[d, "ab"]^2 + 
              2*Subscript[d, "abc"]^2 + 
              (1/2)*(4*Subscript[d, 
                      "ab"]^2 - 
                   2*Subscript[d, "abc"]^
                     2)], Integers]`. I don't believe that saying that a solution would require that condition **also** says that values exist that satisfy that condition.